# Is it possible to bookmark Stack Overflow questions/discussions?

Tags: support, answers, bookmark

Often I read good answers here on Stack Overflow.

Is it possible to bookmark them, like in forums?

Comment: You mean the little star under the vote counts? Click it.

Comment: Oh, how easy. And where do I find them all?

Comment: Go to your user page, there's a **favorites** tab.

Comment: Assuming you thought those answers were good enough to upvote, you can also click on your **votes** tab and see all the questions/answers you voted on.

Comment: It appears to be missing from the Help Center -- I searched for "bookmark", "favorite", and "star". (I should add that I found out how to use it by myself, as it seems a pretty standard function to me.)

Answer (score 14):

> Is it possible to bookmark them, like in forums?

Your wording is a bit ambiguous: "bookmark" could mean a lot of things, but I'm assuming you mean keep it for later reference.

You can star **questions**, which puts them in the [favorites tab](//stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=favorites) of [your profile](//stackoverflow.com/users/current):

[image: Favorites tab]

You can also click the "share" button on any question or answer and bookmark them with your browser as you would with any other URL:

[image: Share button]

Comment: Just right-clicking on the share link and choosing "Bookmark This Link" works for me; no need to fuss with the left-click-triggered pop-out.

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom True, but not all browsers have a bookmarking action in the context menu.

Comment: It is a little difficult to look for a question in favorites when you have some many pages of them.

Also I get in touch again with an answer more in the next few days. For me is common to load them many times, because I keep them as a reference while I am working in a topic for some weeks.

Normally I use to left them open in a tab of the browser, but some times I have a lot of tabs open from other sites and I can not keep them.

Comment: When I go to "favorites" and I would expect to find it ordered by the date I have starred it, or visit it the last time. That is useful because that is more or less the probability that I need them again. 

But they are sorted by the day they where posted. The post date is related more to the moment the creator of the question needed it, not the consumer of the answer. :-(

Comment: Do you save the moment I have marked the question as favorite? Can that be used as a filter ? E.x.:  "starred time" ?