# Idea of bookmarks

Tags: feature-request, bookmarks

I'm using SO for almost 2 years, I learned how it works, and recently I started using the "star" button to collect interesting questions. It's OK so far, as it's the only way (except for browser bookmarks) to save personally-important links.

But it's not always about questions that made me add it to [favourites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251185/is-it-possible-to-bookmark-stackoverflow-questions-discussions). It's sometimes not even about correct answer, but a specific answer (from dozens, sometimes), that maybe didn't solve the issue from a topic, but it solves mine.

The other thing is that I'm interested in more than one coding language. I'm interested in Android, iOS, PHP, HTML and sometimes even more, so it's difficult to sort out what I really need when it comes to find it.

I request this feature so that:

1. Users can collect specific questions and/or answers with bookmarks
2. Users can create many bookmarks, so it's possible to not only sort it by tag or language, but also i.e. by project that user needs answers for.

I know it's a big deal and it would take weeks or even month to accomplish such functionality, but please note that it's my first request here on MSO, so any tips of asking such things are welcome.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfeature-request%5D+favorite