# Can we have a "My Best Answers" section?

Tags: feature-request, answers, profile-page, developer-story

When I am solving a programming problem or learning to do a new task, I often add new answers at Stack Overflow because teaching other people helps me to learn myself. Some of these answers are short and simple, while others are more canonical. Later, after not doing a task for some time, I find myself searching for my old answers to see how I did it before.

Rather than having to search every time, I wish there was a way that I could arrange my answers topically so that I could find the good/useful ones faster. I tried to add this to my profile page once, but the long link addresses brought me to my character limit too fast.

The favorites tab doesn't work for this because I use favorites to star interesting questions that I might like to add an answer to later. Other people have suggested adding bookmarks (see [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252124/idea-of-bookmarks), for example) in which one could bookmark an answer.

Having bookmarks would work, but if there were a tab for "My Best Answers", other people, including potential employers, could see what you feel your best work on Stack Overflow is. One's best answers are not necessary the ones that have the most votes. For those with a wide variety of answers, it could be almost like the index of a programming textbook.

**Update**

I updated my profile page with a rudimentary example. This could work if I strip the links down to be as short as possible, but I would still prefer an separate tab or area of the screen.

Comment: You mean the Answers tab in your profile, sorted by Votes?

Comment: Or like the section on the jobs CV where you can have a curated list of what you feel are your best posts across the network?

Comment: @CodeCaster: No, as I mentioned in my question, the highest voted answers are not always the best ones. Sometimes the good answers haven't had time to collect votes and sometimes they are to low traffic questions. Also there is no topical organization to answers sorted by votes.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Perhaps. I need to look more at that. My initial reaction, though, is that I want to keep my CV private but have this list be public.

Comment: You can always create a showcase on an external website, and link to that from your profile. You can also use short links to your answers by using the "share" link and removing your userid from the URL. This leaves more characters for text in your profile.

Comment: Basically there are dozens of ways to do this sort of thing already, so it seems pretty low priority.

Comment: @CodeCaster: That is useful to know about removing the user id from the URL.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, CodeCaster -  disagree. See my answer.

Comment: [topical organization](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a3681880%20%5bandroid%5d)

Comment: (o_O) ... I have nearly the same type of stuff on my profile and it's been there since many days. Spooky. On a serious note, I do want this feature. Perhaps it may arrive with the dev-stories. :)

Comment: I know it is little bit of topic here. But how does can one use stackoverlfow to land a job? I have just used SO for Q & A so far. Any links would help.

Comment: Along similar lines, I've sometimes thought it would be nice to be able to "star" answers (anybody's, not just your own) -- as you can do for questions.  Obviously you can "star" the question that the answer answers, but this doesn't record which answer it was that caught your eye, and sometimes, it's one aspect of the answer (not necessarily directly to do with answering the question) that's of interest.

Comment: @pratikwebdev http://stackoverflow.com/jobs

Comment: I think something like this would definitely have some positive impact on the state of the site as a whole. A lot of people will search and start cleaning up their answers.

Comment: Alternatively, integrate with [Trello](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trello). It already has a well-developed UI. There could be a read-only view on the Stack Overflow profile. Hiding specific posts could be a list in Trello with a specific name (created automatically as an empty list).

Comment: I would expect `infavorites:me is:a user:me` would work to return my answers to my favorite questions but it doesn't work (`infavorites` selects only questions). You could [generate the list using Data.SE](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/432138/my-answers-to-my-favorite-questions?UserID=4279).

Comment: @Suragch maybe name it **Favorite Answers** - to go along with fav questions.  And maybe don't limit it to just your own answers...

Comment: @cullub: That would be fine with me if I were also able to organize them in my own way by topic (and not just by tag). The current favorite questions tab is better than nothing but it tends to turn into a big unorganized mess of things to go back to some day.

Comment: So kind of like the "Select Publications" list that people in certain fields put on their resume/CV. This is a good idea :)

Comment: Agreed, 'sort by personal preference' basically.

Answer (score 96):

Great idea. It would basically mean porting the Careers feature where you get to control which answers to feature.

That makes a lot of sense. Your highest voted answers are often enough meaningless in terms of quality; I was so ashamed of a couple of mine that I even culled a half dozen of them when I applied for a job a while ago. (There's still some left that are [the result of a bit of Googling rather than deep, thoughtful programming insight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654447/whats-the-difference-between-scss-and-sass/5654471#5654471) - would *love* a way of hiding those.)

The "you can already do this on your external website" argument seems a bit lame, given that this is something that would make a lot of sense as a native feature. In fact, users *do* use their profile field for this; that's OK, but some of us would like to use that for its intended purpose rather than work around a missing feature.

Comment: I just played around with the Top answers feature in Careers. Something similar would be nice, but I would like to see something less bulky (no need to include tags under every line) and maybe have a bit of hierarchical organization (indent subtopics).

Comment: If you are so ashamed then you can always request it to be "anonymized" and will be completely disassociated from you :P

Comment: @l3x but...... MY ILL-GOTTEN REPZ!!!!!!!!

Comment: Same here, I would love to hide my ridiculous top answer. It's so trivial, it essentially says RTFM.

Comment: @JoshCrozier Probably the most important advice there is. :)

Comment: To be fair, the ability to quickly find a reliable answer using the web is a valuable skill in almost any job... But you're right, probably not the best highlight for a profile.

Comment: For quite some time my top voted ans was a one-liner. :D

Comment: I'm not embarrassed by the answers I generated through Google - good Googling is a skill too.

Comment: @Josh Crozier: One of my top answers is ["you have a typo, it should be X"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389932/how-do-you-disable-viewport-zooming-on-mobile-safari/4389976#4389976), and practically everyone voting and commenting on the Q&A has found the answer useful ignoring the typo aspect of the question. The question was resolved in a manner unlikely to help readers, but that hasn't stopped it from becoming a top Google result.

Comment: @MarkRansom yeah, there's absolutely nothing wrong with Googled answers. Just as a prominent example in a context where you're trying to show you can do original thinking, solve complex problems, etc. it feels... not ideal.

Comment: @BoltClock FYI Someone edited that question. The edit removes the problem from the post.

Comment: Something like the Careers feature is exactly what I'd want; crucially, though, I'd want the list to be separate from the list on my StackOverflow CV, because there are [posts](http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/q/931/52) I might want to highlight because I find them interesting that are in no way relevant to my CV.

Comment: @BoltClock "The question was resolved in a manner unlikely to help readers, but that hasn't stopped it from becoming a top Google result." Heh. To me that kinda reads like "the question was resolved in a manner unlikely to help readers, but it still helped a ton of readers anyway". =P

Comment: @Ajedi32: Exactly! Just not in the way the question intended. Happy accidents and all.

Answer (score 4):

Well, I couldn't agree more, since I've suggested it to add on [Developer Story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/313970/1064325):

> **What might be missing**
>
> I often see users using their profile to:
>
> - List their own favorite contributions (questions and answers)
> - List their best achievements (badges and tag badges)
> - Provide a donation wishlist (books and assets)

Answer (score -3):

Your goal is to search your own old posts for relevant information.

So searching your own old posts it shall be.

http://data.stackexchange.com has [a number of queries](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?q=search%20my%20posts) that do this. As you can see, each user typically creates one-time scripts for oneself (probably because making (or finding) general-purpose long-term-use scripts is non-straightforward @data.SE).

**In fact, the current search already supports such a filter: `user:<id>` or `user:me`.** (But the syntax help is hidden under the "advanced search tips" JS link in the [search view](https://stackoverflow.com/search) so it can't even be hyperlinked to.)

Since this proves to be a recurring task, maybe it warrants a separate UI feature (or a general UI for advanced search so that the user fills in form fields but sees the resulting syntax in results, like Google does).

I don't think that "organizing" the posts manually in any way will help you find anything faster than typing a few keywords into a search box. That's because

- by the nature of this task, you never know what you will need the next day
- all posts @ SO are rather homogeneous, with comparable (and rather limited) scope and with no clear hierarchy (the only hierarchy here is tags).

This, of course, doesn't address the other mentioned goal - advertising yourself to others (as the latter involves no search terms beside the user ID).

Comment: Maybe give some code examples... of a query (or queries) that would do this.

Comment: @cullub did you, like, follow the link I gave specifically for that?

Comment: @ivan_opzdeev Well, no, you can't expect every uninterested user to go around clinking links before asking stupid questions, can you? :-)  But now I see that your link (second one, for the record) linked to something worth looking at.  I still think it would be nice if you could add even *one* query of code, though... :)

Comment: @cullub they are all roughly the same, so the link's purpose was to show the general picture. See other critical updates, too.

Answer (score -7):

> ## Can we have a “My Best Answers” section?**

Sounds like a great idea. But to me it seems that

## You already have one

This counterpoint immediately caught my eye:

> You mean the Answers tab in your profile, sorted by Votes?
>    - [CodeCaster](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315994/can-we-have-a-my-best-answers-section?cb=1#comment301935_315994)

I agree with this sentiment - that's one way that I use *my* answers tab, so that I can immediately see the content that I've created that others will see.

## Ideas against Top Answers by Votes

Your response was:

> @CodeCaster: No, as I mentioned in my question, the highest voted
>   answers are not always the best ones. Sometimes the good answers
>   haven't had time to collect votes and sometimes they are to low
>   traffic questions. Also there is no topical organization to answers
>   sorted by votes.

And Pekka similarly wrote:

> Your highest voted answers are often enough meaningless in terms of
>   quality; I was so ashamed of a couple of mine that I even culled a
>   half dozen of them when I applied for a job a while ago.

## My Personal View

Ok, so at this point I feel the need to point out that, even years after writing an answer, there's this little *edit* link at the bottom of your answer.

If you look at this answer of mine, it's currently one of my top five. The last time I touched it was in December less than a couple of months ago. I first created the answer more than 2 years prior.

[image]

## Curate Your Answers

You are allowed, and in fact, *encouraged* to continue updating your content.

I understand that's why we've removed the automatic conversion to Community Wiki, so that you would not be penalized from continuously curating your content.

If you have a link-only answer saying RTFM, at least quote some of the important documentation.

If you have a copy and paste and a link, then expand on it in your own words.

If you have a small answer in your own words, break it down so that any new person will learn a lot from you and any experienced person will see that you know your stuff. Then, add some headings, link to some documentation, RFC's, and mailing list archives, and you've got yourself a great answer that others will upvote for your pure effort.

And then, your top answers will *be* your top answers.

## Keep your low-vote curation links in your profile

I also keep a list of answers that I curate (that I feel haven't gotten enough attention yet) in my profile - *after* I quote some of my preferred guiding principles for contributing to StackOverflow. I don't know if people see it. One guy mentioned that he did, so maybe they do. I don't know.

I *do* know that it's there for me to use whenever I want, and I can organize it however I like.

Comment: For me, I would like an easy way to get back to some of the more canonical answers that I have written. For example, I wrote [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34922332) a couple weeks to help myself learn about getting and setting the cursor position. It doesn't currently have any votes and will certainly never be one of my top voted answers. However, I've found myself going back to it again and again in order to remind myself how to do it. I have a lot of other answers like that as well. I can do a search of my own answers for keywords but that's slower than an organized list would be.

Comment: Other people may have a different motivation (for example, showing a potential employer what their best work is), but the issue is still the same: quality answers on low traffic questions will never be one's top answers according to vote count. Also, vote count does not provide topical organization.

Comment: "I also keep a list of answers that I curate (that I feel haven't gotten enough attention yet) in my profile " -- okay, so you're doing exactly what OP is doing and working around the fact that this feature doesn't exist, and you are fully aware that the way you're doing it, that curated list probably isn't getting much attention. How does this constitute disagreement with OP's request, exactly? Moreover, note that if you fill your "about me" section with post links, you can't post much other interesting information.