# How can I search through my own answers?

Tags: feature-request, answers, search

I recently came across a question on the main SO site which I thought was a duplicate of a question I already had answered sometime ago.

Now, my problem is, to find my own old answer, I had to scroll through all the answers I have ever posted.
That wasn't much of a problem (*since I have a mere 70 or so answers till date*), but, this could become cumbersome later-on.

Is there a way to attach some personal keywords to my answers (*say, the ones that may be required frequently*) and some way to search through only the answers I have posted? That will be super time-saver feature!

([This question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/315994/can-we-have-a-my-best-answers-section), is related, but, different!)

Comment: Visit your profile and the search box will be pre-filled to search your own posts. The "advanced search help" page will give you more tips on... advanced searching.

Comment: Also an alternative - you can type `user:me` in the search bar (and add more search terms if you want) and when you start the search, the system is going to fill in your user ID.

Comment: Yes, that works if you don't already have all user IDs memorized, @user3689450. But who among us would be so lazy?